# Building XCode project for Blender using CMake on OS X 10.10

Tags: xcode5, blender, xcode6, osx-yosemite

**Context:**

I've been having issues running blender on OSX10.10 (this is early release software unfortunately I really should try to use it if at all possible).

Specifically:

---

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Thread 0:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

0   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x97dc34ed CFStringGetCString + 29

1   org.blenderfoundation.blender   0x00338953 fsmenu_read_system + 851

2   org.blenderfoundation.blender   0x0033a398 ED_file_init + 72

3   org.blenderfoundation.blender   0x00011df5 WM_init + 133

4   org.blenderfoundation.blender   0x00002cd4 main + 660

5   org.blenderfoundation.blender   0x00002a35 start + 53

---

As this error doesn't look threatening (admittedly it may hide 100 others...) I decided to try building Blender.

**Question**

Getting a proper config with CMake is proving arduous. I keep getting something like:

---

Detected system-version: unsupported
Xcode-bundle : /Applications/Xcode.app
Detected Xcode-version: 5.1.1
OSX_SYSROOT_PREFIX: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform
Performing Test SUPPORT_SSE_BUILD
CMake Warning at /Applications/CMake 2.8-12.app/Contents/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/Platform/Darwin.cmake:179 (message):
Ignoring CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT value:

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSXunsupported.sdk

because the directory does not exist.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
/Applications/CMake 2.8-12.app/Contents/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CMakeSystemSpecificInformation.cmake:36 (include)
CMakeLists.txt:3 (PROJECT)

CMake Error at /Applications/CMake 2.8-12.app/Contents/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/Platform/Darwin.cmake:211 (message):
CMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET is '10.6' but CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT:

""

is not set to a MacOSX SDK with a recognized version. Either set
CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT to a valid SDK or set CMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET to
empty.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
/Applications/CMake 2.8-12.app/Contents/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CMakeSystemSpecificInformation.cmake:36 (include)
CMakeLists.txt:3 (PROJECT)

CMake Error: Internal CMake error, TryCompile configure of cmake failed
Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/Users/xxx/blender-build/cmake/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".

---

While this may appear to be self explanatory, the catch is that I manually set CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT to a valid (at least an existing) SDK before pressing condigure/generate and it replaces whatever I choose by MacOSXunsupported.sdk every time...

I am not familiar with CMake. I use the GUI interface but any explanation that can point in the right direction would help.

I tried pointing at both XCode5 and 6, although looking at the matching output it would appear that CMake is intent on using the XCode version located in 'Applications/XCode'(The gui doesn't seem to provide an option to select a specific version of XCode )

For reference, I used the instructions provided here:

[http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Doc/Building_Blender/Mac](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev%3aDoc/Building_Blender/Mac)

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are seeing running Blender seems to be because of new iCloud stuff... there is a fix checked in if you wana try https://developer.blender.org/rB86f42ee33137897ec08ddde0fdcd2d1087ea78dc

I'm having the same issue, haven't tried building Blender yet with this fix but it should work.

Comment: I grabbed the nightly which has this fix in it from https://developer.blender.org/buildbot/ and it seems to be working fine.

Comment: thanks for this. I got myself setup with 2 partitions and two OSes but hey... good to know, was even considering removing my question at this stage.